# Inverse image of a polynomial in two variables is simply-connected?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I'm wondering if the following is true:

> Suppose $p: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ is a complex polynomial where the degree in each variable is at least 1. Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there exists an $N>0$ such that the set $N-\epsilon <|p(z,w)|< N + \epsilon$ is simply-connected in each connected component.

Comment: Is your question equivalent to: "For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $M>0$ such that $M<|p|<M+\epsilon$..."?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin Yes

Comment: But are you sure that you wanna look at the set $M<|p(z,w)|<M+\epsilon$? Isnt that just an interval on the real line?

Comment: Oh, it is not. It is a domain in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: But can we here fix $z$ and  transform regions with $p$ and then fix $w$ and transform regions with $p$, are you after that?